# Azure Artifacts Credential Provider not authenticating with PAT during Docker build

Tags: azure, docker, azure-artifacts

I have a simple .NET 6 C# Web API that I want to host in a Linux container. It has some package dependencies hosted in a private Azure Artifact Feed. I want to use the [Azure Artifacts Credential Provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/blob/master/README.md), since this will eventually be built in an Azure build pipeline (and I want to inject credentials for the feed through a variable).

**THE ISSUE**

When I run the build, it fails with this error:

```
#17 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet restore \"./My.Project/My.Project.csproj\" --configfile ./nuget.config" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [build 5/9] RUN dotnet restore "./My.Project/My.Project.csproj" --configfile ./nuget.config:
#17 1.686   Determining projects to restore...
#17 8.947 /src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 14.94 /src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 21.45 /src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
... 4 more retries
#17 53.23   Failed to restore /src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj (in 51.11 sec).
------
Dockerfile:27
--------------------
  25 |     COPY ["nuget.config", "./"]
  26 |
  27 | >>> RUN dotnet restore "./My.Project/My.Project.csproj" --configfile ./nuget.config
  28 |     RUN rm ./nuget.config
  29 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet restore \"./My.Project/My.Project.csproj\" --configfile ./nuget.config" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

**CONTEXT**

My project has a nuget.config file to configure the private feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="some-feed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

(no package credentials at this point, which is by design)

My Dockerfile is as follows (unnecessary bits removed):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

# Install curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

# Install Azure Artifact Credential Provider
RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh)"

# Specify an argument for the feed's access token (PAT)
ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN

# Configure VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS environment variable with passed in arg
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"

# Sanity check to see if arg gets injected
RUN echo $VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS >&2

# Sanity check to see if AACP was installed
RUN ls /root/.nuget/plugins/netcore/CredentialProvider.Microsoft

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["My.Project.csproj", "My.Project/"]
COPY ["nuget.config", "./"]

RUN dotnet restore "./My.Project/My.Project.csproj" --configfile ./nuget.config
RUN rm ./nuget.config

WORKDIR "/src/My.Project"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "My.Project" -c Release -o /app/build

... do some publish things
```

The build is run like this:

```
docker build --build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=%SOME-ENV-VARIABLE% --progress=plain  -t myproject .
```

(fwiw the PAT was issued with Packaging (Read) permissions)

**In Sanity Check 1** the output looks as follows:

```
#10 [base 4/6] RUN echo {"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"docker", "password":"my_pat"}]}
#0 0.715 {"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"docker", "password":"my_pat"}]}
```

**In Sanity Check 2** this output is shown, confirming AACP is installed:

```
#11 [base 5/6] RUN ls /root/.nuget/plugins/netcore/CredentialProvider.Microsoft
#11 0.805 CredentialProvider.Microsoft.deps.json
#11 0.805 CredentialProvider.Microsoft.dll
#11 0.805 CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe
#11 0.805 CredentialProvider.Microsoft.pdb
... some more files
#11 0.805 runtimes
#11 DONE 0.9s
```

**Manually specifying the PAT in my nuget.config file works**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="some-feed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <some-feed>
            <add key="Username" value="docker" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="my_pat" />
        </some-feed>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Which results in:

```
#17 7.497   Restored /src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj (in 6 sec). # Yay
```

`<edit start>`
As per Jonathan's comment, I also executed the `dotnet restore` with `--verbosity detailed`, which didn't expose any other errors that could indicate why this is failing. There are also no references in the log to "auth", "credential", "provider", "VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS", or "CredentialProvider.Microsoft".

Some bits of info I got from this is below:

```
#17 1.066        Task "GetRestoreDotnetCliToolsTask"
#17 1.067          (in) ProjectPath '/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj'
#17 1.067          (in) DotnetCliToolReferences ''
#17 1.067          (in) RestoreSources 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json'
#17 1.067          (in) RestorePackagesPath '/root/.nuget/packages/'
#17 1.067          (in) RestoreConfigFilePaths '/src/nuget.config'
#17 1.067        Done executing task "GetRestoreDotnetCliToolsTask".
```

From the above I gather my nuget.config file is being correctly interpreted.

The "Target" where it seems like the actual restore is happening output this:

```
#17 1.087      1>Target "Restore" in file "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/NuGet.targets" from project "/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj" (entry point):
#17 1.087        Task "RemoveDuplicates"
#17 1.087        Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
#17 1.087        Using "RestoreTask" task from assembly "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll".
#17 1.087        Task "RestoreTask"
#17 1.089          (in) RestoreGraphItems Count '13'
#17 1.089          (in) RestoreDisableParallel 'False'
#17 1.089          (in) RestoreNoCache 'False'
#17 1.089          (in) RestoreIgnoreFailedSources 'False'
#17 1.089          (in) RestoreRecursive 'True'
#17 1.089          (in) RestoreForce 'False'
#17 1.089          (in) HideWarningsAndErrors 'False'
#17 1.089          (in) RestoreForceEvaluate 'False'
#17 1.089          (in) RestorePackagesConfig 'False'
#17 1.187          X.509 certificate chain validation will use the fallback certificate bundle at '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/trustedroots/codesignctl.pem'.
#17 1.294          Running restore with 12 concurrent jobs.
#17 1.295          Reading project file /src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj.
#17 1.353          Restoring packages for /src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj...
#17 1.357          Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
#17 8.330      1>/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 14.53      1>/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 20.86      1>/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 27.09      1>/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 33.16      1>/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 39.49      1>/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 45.77      1>/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 51.90      1>/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
#17 51.92          Checking compatibility of packages on net6.0.
#17 51.92          All packages and projects are compatible with net6.0.
#17 51.93          Committing restore...
#17 51.93          Generating MSBuild file /src/My.Project/obj/My.Project.csproj.nuget.g.props.
#17 51.93          Generating MSBuild file /src/My.Project/obj/My.Project.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
#17 51.93          Writing assets file to disk. Path: /src/My.Project/obj/project.assets.json
#17 51.94          Writing cache file to disk. Path: /src/My.Project/obj/project.nuget.cache
#17 51.95          Persisting dg to /src/My.Project/obj/My.Project.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
#17 51.95          Failed to restore /src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj (in 50.63 sec).
#17 51.96
#17 51.96          NuGet Config files used:
#17 51.96              /src/nuget.config
#17 51.96
#17 51.96          Feeds used:
#17 51.96              https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json
#17 51.96        Done executing task "RestoreTask" -- FAILED.
#17 51.96      1>Done building target "Restore" in project "My.Project.csproj" -- FAILED.
#17 51.96      1>Done Building Project "/src/My.Project/My.Project.csproj" (Restore target(s)) -- FAILED.
#17 51.96
#17 51.96 Build FAILED.
```

`<edit end>`

So:

1. The credentials/PAT is good
2. The Azure Artifact Credential Provider is installed
3. The VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS environment variable gets set to the correct value

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add `--verbosity detailed` to the dotnet command line and see if there are any messages about credential providers?

Comment: Good shout. Did this, which generated a (very) long output. Searched through this for references to "credential" or "provider"... no results. Updated the question with some more debugging info from this.

Answer (score 3):

Spent unnecessary hours just to figure out my Dockerfile was wrong. Was installing the AACP in the base image, and tried building in the build image.

So, instead of this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh)"
ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"
RUN echo $VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS >&2
RUN ls /root/.nuget/plugins/netcore/CredentialProvider.Microsoft

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["My.Project.csproj", "My.Project/"]
COPY ["nuget.config", "./"]

RUN dotnet restore "./My.Project/My.Project.csproj" --configfile ./nuget.config
RUN rm ./nuget.config

WORKDIR "/src/My.Project"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "My.Project" -c Release -o /app/build

... do some publish things
```

It should've been this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
    
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/someguid/_packaging/some-feed/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"    
RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.sh)"

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["My.Project.csproj", "My.Project/"]
COPY ["nuget.config", "./"]

RUN dotnet restore "./My.Project/My.Project.csproj" --configfile ./nuget.config
RUN rm ./nuget.config

WORKDIR "/src/My.Project"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "My.Project" -c Release -o /app/build

... do some publish things
```

The `--verbosity detailed` then output:

```
#13 1.271          Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
#13 2.722          Using /root/.nuget/plugins/netcore/CredentialProvider.Microsoft/CredentialProvider.Microsoft.dll as a credential provider plugin.
#13 3.075              [CredentialProvider.230950]Running in plug-in mode
#13 3.076              [CredentialProvider.230950]Command-line v1.0.5+501a6eafccfe6b97a80a7b7f89b1022d3618a4b1: /root/.nuget/plugins/netcore/CredentialProvider.Microsoft/CredentialProvider.Microsoft.dll -Plugin
```